# How to add Navigation Drawer beside tab fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, navigation-drawer

I made a project with a `MainActivity` which has two tabs (and two fragments).
I tried to add `NavigationDrawer` but I had some errors that says I can not add this beside my tabView. How can i do this correctly?

This is my `MainActivity` :

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        setupDrawerContent (nvDrawer);

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentOne.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentTwo.class.getName()));

        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

//        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);
//        pager.setPageMargin(3);
//        pager.setPageMargin(getResources()
//                .getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.viewpager_margin));


        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            }
        };

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Pg 01").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Pg 02").setTabListener(tabListener));

        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

    }

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer,
                mToolbar, R.string.draver_open, R.string.draver_close);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent (NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected (MenuItem menuItem) {
                selectDrawerItem (menuItem);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem (MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
                fragmentClass = FragmentOne.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
                fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
                fragmentClass = FragmentTwo.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = FragmentOne.class;
        }
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.flContent, fragment)
                .commit();

        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

and here is my `layout` named `activity_fragment` for `MainActivity` :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">         
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />         
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout> 
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" 
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/activity_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="com.drgnme.listhamrah.MainActivity"> 
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is `nav_header.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="192dp"
              android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
              android:padding="16dp"
              android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
              android:gravity="bottom">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is `toolbar.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and this is `drawer_view.xml` in `res/menu` :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_first_fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_one"
            android:title="One"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_second_fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_two"
            android:title="Two"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_third_fragment"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_three"
            android:title="Three"/>

        <item android:title="Sub items">
              <menu>
                  <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                      <item
                          android:icon="@drawable/ic_one"
                          android:title="Sub item 01"/>
                      <item
                          android:icon="@drawable/ic_three"
                          android:title="Sub item 02"/>
                  </group>
              </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

and finally this is my Error in logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.drgnme.listhamrah, PID: 25783
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.drgnme.listhamrah/com.drgnme.listhamrah.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tabs not supported in this configuration
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tabs not supported in this configuration
                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.setNavigationMode(ToolbarActionBar.java:320)
                                                                       at com.drgnme.listhamrah.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Where you are adding NavigationDrawer?

Comment: in my `MainActivity` and it's xml file

Comment: What is the actual text of the error message copied and pasted from logcat?

Comment: There is no `DrawerLayout` in your layout XML. You need to show how you tried to add it, so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: @MikeM. i did it

Comment: @nasch i added my error, check it out

Comment: `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` has been deprecated, and it will [unconditionally throw that `IllegalArgumentException`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ToolbarActionBar.java#312) if you try to set it on a support `ActionBar`. Currently, [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) is the recommended replacement.

Comment: @MikeM. so what should i do? i want a navigation drawer comes on top of my TabLayout of course

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Just add a `TabLayout` somewhere in the main content - the `LinearLayout` - and set that up with the `ViewPager`. Also, that `RelativeLayout` should not be there. You shouldn't have anything listed after the drawer `NavigationView`. Move the `ViewPager` to inside the `LinearLayout` somewhere, and get rid of the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @MikeM. i did, it worked